# Command for clicking GUI application?

Tags: command-line, gui

In Dash, I can search an application e.g. mplayer, and click to run it.

In terminal, when I run the application e.g. mplayer, it is usually not the same as how I run it from Dash (no menu and progress bar in mplayer)

How can I find out what command and options clicking mplayer icon invokes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag the icon from the Dash into a Terminal. You'll get something like

```
application://mplayer.desktop
```

Now search for a file named `mplayer.desktop` in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` and `/usr/share/applications`. In that file search for a line starting with `Exec=`. After the `=` there's the command to run, maybe with something like `%f` or `%U` instead of the file name.

Or install [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax), open it and drag the icon into the window. The command will be in the `Command` field.

Comment: or simply `gedit /usr/share/applications/mplayer.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Open MPlayer from the Dash and then open the System Monitor and search the list of open processes in the Processes tab to find the Process Name of the open mplayer process.